# Postgre, is of type date but expression is of type text

Tags: postgresql

i have error

ERROR:  column "portfolio_end_date" is of type date but expression is of type text
LINE 5: portfolio_end_date = tmp.portfolio_end_date,
^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
SQL state: 42804
Character: 186

Why potgre retrun error

```
UPDATE ods2.project_portfolios as tbl 
set id_portfolio = tmp.id_portfolio,
id_project_link = tmp.id_project_link,
portfolio_start_date = tmp.portfolio_start_date,
portfolio_end_date = tmp.portfolio_end_date, 
id_employee = tmp.id_employee,
portfolio_changed_date = tmp.portfolio_changed_date,
portfolio_quarter = tmp.portfolio_quarter,
end_month = tmp.end_month,
historicity_time = tmp.historicity_time
from (
values (
    491533570142,
    25, 
    '2022-07-01'::date,
    NULL,
    51,
    '2023-02-28 14:27:24'::timestamp,

    NULL,
        '2022-07-01'::date,
    '2023-03-20 23:00:16'::timestamp)
) as tmp(
    id_portfolio, id_project_link, portfolio_start_date, portfolio_end_date, id_employee,
    portfolio_changed_date, portfolio_quarter, end_month, historicity_time)
    where tbl.id_portfolio = tmp.id_portfolio and tbl.historicity_time between 
    '2023-05-25 00:00:00' and '2023-05-25 23:59:59';
```

Request fails although I don't see any errors in it

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and the full complete error message, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Further clearly describe what you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element in a `VALUES` statement is not a number and is not explicitly cast to a different data type, it will resolve as type `text`:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(col)
FROM (VALUES (NULL)) AS v(col);

 pg_typeof 
═══════════
 text
(1 row)
```

Now there is no assignment cast between `text` and `date`:

```
\dC date

                                      List of casts
         Source type         │         Target type         │  Function   │   Implicit?   
═════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════
 date                        │ timestamp with time zone    │ timestamptz │ yes
 date                        │ timestamp without time zone │ timestamp   │ yes
 timestamp with time zone    │ date                        │ date        │ in assignment
 timestamp without time zone │ date                        │ date        │ in assignment
(4 rows)
```

Therefore you get the error you observe.

Add an explicit type cast:

```
UPDATE ods2.project_portfolios 
SET portfolio_end_date = tmp.portfolio_end_date, ...
FROM (VALUES (CAST (NULL AS date), ...)) AS tmp (portfolio_end_date, ...)
WHERE ...;
```